# JDBC client to Hive - No data or no sasl data in the stream Exception

Tags: authentication, jdbc, hive, kerberos, oozie

We have a Kerberised cluster and I'm trying to run a Java action in Oozie where I make a JDBC connection to Hive. This JDBC connections works fine on the Sandbox without Kerberos.

The connection string is as simple as the following, where I'm providing username and password in it:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://W12345:10000/control;principal=hive/W12345.companynet.net@COMPANYNET.NET","user123","passw123");
```

The Oozie action (strangely) completes succesfully, and the Java action log does not present any error:

```
1742 [main] INFO org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils  - Supplied authorities: W12345:10000
1742 [main] INFO org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils  - Resolved authority: W12345:10000
1766 [main] INFO org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection  - Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://W12345:10000/control;principal=hive/W12345.companynet.net@COMPANYNET.NET
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
Oozie Launcher ends
1785 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task:attempt_1464245290012_0129_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
1847 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task attempt_1464245290012_0129_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
1854 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter  - Saved output of task 'attempt_1464245290012_0129_m_000000_0' to hdfs://danskehadoop/user/user123/oozie-oozi/0000013-160527101253015-oozie-oozi-W/JavaAction--java/output/_temporary/1/task_1464245290012_0129_m_000000
1909 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task 'attempt_1464245290012_0129_m_000000_0' done.
```

But in reality the Java main does not complete correctly the execution (and does not execute the needed queries) because the JDBC connection fails with an exception that I can see only in the Hive log:

```
    ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-78363]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(296)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:739)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1637)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
  at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:328)
  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
  ... 10 more
```

I'm actually connected to the cluster, and already done further kinit on my username.

Does anybody know what could the cause of this exception be?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Antonio

Comment: It seems missing hadoop configuration in your action, could you please try providing hive-site.xml & core-site.xml into your oozie action node. which might resolve your issue.

Comment: *"already done further kinit on my username"* -- did you run that `kinit` on every YARN node, so that the Oozie job has a chance to get a local ticket?

Comment: *"I'm actually connected to the cluster"* -- the Hive JDBC driver does not give a shit about Hadoop configuration and Hadoop delegation tokens, it's 100% raw Thrift protocol *(in binary mode by default since you don't request HTTP mode in your URL)*; if the URL contains a "principal" entry then any user/password entries are ignored, the driver switches to Kerberos authentication using **whatever JAAS configuration file has been set as default for the JVM**. Looks like you've got some research to do on JAAS.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on MapR hadoop distribution platform. 
In my case it was Keepalived checking Hive port every 5 seconds and producing such error. I simply used "nc" command to check if Hive port is in use and did not use any authentication method. Later I switched to "maprcli" command which uses SASL authentication and the error was gone.

Comment: Please don't post answers that consist largely of references to external sites. Those sites might go away, and with them, the substance of your response. Synthesize what the external resource has to offer the original poster.

Comment: Thank you @chb for the heads up. I have removed the reference and explained in more details.